# Jquery conflict issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using many js file in my header file as shown below

```
<script src="{$BASE_URL}js/jquery.form.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="{$BASE_URL}js/cmxforms.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="{$BASE_URL}js/jquery.metadata.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="{$BASE_URL}js/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="{$BASE_URL}js/functions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="{$BASE_URL}js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="{$BASE_URL}js/jquery-ui.min.js" > </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{$BASE_URL}js/timepicker/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{$BASE_URL}js/jquery-ui-sliderAccess.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{$BASE_URL}js/jspatch.js"></script>
<script src="{$BASE_URL}js/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
```

I am getting error as below.

```
$(...).live is not a function in    

$("#reset").live('click',function(){

findproject (line 925)


SyntaxError: syntax error


<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA

$(...).validate is not a function
```

So, what the issue. I am not getting exact way. validation functality is not working

Answer (score 2):

You need to put core jquery lib at the top as this is required to resolve dependencies of other jquery library-

```
<!-- This must be first library to inlcude-->
<script src="{$BASE_URL}js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>

<script src="{$BASE_URL}js/jquery.form.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="{$BASE_URL}js/cmxforms.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="{$BASE_URL}js/jquery.metadata.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="{$BASE_URL}js/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="{$BASE_URL}js/functions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="{$BASE_URL}js/jquery-ui.min.js" > </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{$BASE_URL}js/timepicker/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{$BASE_URL}js/jquery-ui-sliderAccess.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{$BASE_URL}js/jspatch.js"></script>
<script src="{$BASE_URL}js/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
```

Also `.live()` is not available with this version, you should use `.on()`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `.live()` use `.on()` because `.live()` is deprecated since Jquery 1.7 and removed after Jquery 1.9+ versions and try reordering your Jquery file as shown :-

```
<!-- This must be first library to inlcude-->
<script src="{$BASE_URL}js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>

<script src="{$BASE_URL}js/jquery.form.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="{$BASE_URL}js/cmxforms.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="{$BASE_URL}js/jquery.metadata.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="{$BASE_URL}js/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="{$BASE_URL}js/functions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="{$BASE_URL}js/jquery-ui.min.js" > </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{$BASE_URL}js/timepicker/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{$BASE_URL}js/jquery-ui-sliderAccess.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{$BASE_URL}js/jspatch.js"></script>
<script src="{$BASE_URL}js/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `on` instead of `live`:

```
$("#reset").on('click', function () {
    // ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to include `jquery.js` first in the page, as other script will rely on it:

```
<script src="{$BASE_URL}js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> <!-- < First -->
<script src="{$BASE_URL}js/jquery.form.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="{$BASE_URL}js/cmxforms.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="{$BASE_URL}js/jquery.metadata.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="{$BASE_URL}js/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="{$BASE_URL}js/functions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Secondly, `live` has been removed from the latest versions of jQuery. You need to use the delegated version of `on()` instead.